cloning submodules with ssh when using k8s runner
I want to switch from dind runners to k8s in my jobs in gitlab
k8s executor runner has already been configured, I was only told to set the k8s runner tag and my docker image in ci
I did so, but when cloning the repository I see the following error:
Cloning into '/builds/123...
error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
fatal: clone of 'git@git.123.git' into submodule path '/builds/123' failed
Failed to clone '123'. Retry scheduled

my image has an ssh client (when I go into the container the ssh command works fine)
but I don’t really understand how cloning via ssh into a docker image via k8s executor works, because I don’t specify my key anywhere...
please tell me what I need to do for the submodule to clone? or where to read?

try specifying a fully qualified path to ssh

it worked by specifying relative paths to the project
thanks
